# How should I connect four resistors to double the capacity with the same resistor?

Tags: resistors, resistance, watts

I know that putting two resistors in parallel will double the wattage from the input to output, but only with half the resistance.

**Example Parallel Circuit:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcXrmK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I know that putting two resistors in series will double the resistance, with the same wattage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flfTQO.png)</sup>

---

**However:** I need to double the wattage without the affecting resistance. **Would this work?:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEoBUc.png)</sup>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your four resistor circuit will give you 100 ohms at 2 watts.

Comment: Succinct and to the point +1

Comment: Just watch out for thermal runaway.

Comment: Are we seeing different circuits or am I just so tired that I'm messing up the simplest calculations? I don't see 50 ohms in that last circuit.

Comment: I agree with @us2012, I'm not seeing why it would be 50Ω OR 2W.

Comment: Ummm - I'm not seeing 50 ohms either - it should obviously be 100 ohms, 2 watts (can't trust these keyboards  :-)  )

Comment: Requirement for 2 watts: the four resistors are mounted far enough apart that they don't heat each other.

Answer (score 1):

No.   It will not work as a 50R load, rather it is 100R and you get twice the resistance and  4x the W capacity, not twice the power with four parts.

If the wanted twice the power, you only need 2x equal values.  If you wanted 4x the power, your simulation would work at 50 Ohms using 4x 200R in parallel or 4x 12R5 in series might be possible , but only in theory as this is not a common value.

The sensible solution is your circuit with 50R parts. i.e. 1/4W in 2S2P array to handle 1W @ 50R.

> Using N parts of equal value in symmetrical arrays gives you N times
> the power capacity and the same resistance as the each resistor, because it is linear.
>
> In the case of  batteries and LEDs, you may increase the string voltage and current and increase
> power capacity by N times using N EQUAL parts.  The array you created is strings of 2 elements in
> series with 2 strings in parallel, using standard notation would be
> 2S2P.  The same notation is used with LED arrays and batteries to increase power in rechargeable batteries, with care taken to ensure they are equal at all times by design. E.g. Add ESR to LED's to "normalize" and limit current or add shunt limiters to large battery arrays to match each cell.

.

Comment: They want 100Ω at the end...